# Simpledialog2 Open partial view inside it

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, simpledialog

I was working on ASP.NET MVC3 application. I want to render my site on mobile as well .

```
function openpopup() {
    $('#registerform').simpledialog2({
        mode: 'blank',
    headerText: 'Some Stuff',
    headerClose: true,
    blankContent : 
  "<ul data-role='listview'><li>Some</li><li>List</li><li>Items</li></ul>"+

  "<a rel='close' data-role='button' href='#'>Close</a>"
    })
    }
```

Now I want to open my partial view inside this simpledialog2 . How can I open it?
My partial view is

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPopup", Model)
```

Any Help?

Comment: opening such popups in mobile devices wont work properly or as expected. use a different stylesheet or view for mobile device.

Comment: @shakthi simpledialog are specially designed for mobile platform only